How do I delete/remove part of the line between two words in the entire log file in gvim/vim
How do I delete/remove part of the line between two words in the entire log file in gVim/Vim
from (original line):
abc xyz mnp 123 

to (updated line):
abc 123 --> remove xyz to mnp of line.

pls. help in this regard.
:g/abc * 123/normal nD


I would actually shell out to sed for this sort of thing, but you can do:
:g/abc.*123/s//abc 123/

This (maybe) does not do what you want if you have multiple occurrences on a line, and normally using a g flag is appropriate, but in this case the pattern is too greedy and multiple occurrences will all get glommed together by the .*.  If that is an issue, you would need to refine the pattern or make it non-greedy with something like:
:g/abc.\{-}123/s//abc 123/g

or
:g/\(abc\).\{-}\(123\)/s//\1 \2/g


Sounds like yet another case for the :substitute command with its fellows, the start and end match atoms: \zs and \ze, respectively.
The following command will remove everything between "abc" and "123":
:%s/^abc\zs.*\ze123$/ /

Where ^ anchors abc to the start of line,
\zs starts capture, .* is just a greedy match all and
\ze ends capture.
It is followed by 123 and the end of line $.
All of this needs to be there but only the stuff between \zs and \ze is part of the final match.
The matched part of the line is replaced with a space, effectively deleting it.
Documentation on these features can be found with :help :substitute and :help /\zs.

Try:
:new | r ! sed -E 's/^([a-z]+) .+( [0-9]+)$/\1\2/' #

You can be more or less specific using character classes.

new: opens a horizontally-split buffer above current buffer.
r ! <command> reads the output of the command into the new buffer.
#: represents the filename of the current buffer.

There is a good discussion about these vim commands here.

As I understood the question, the replacement should happen in the current buffer. Creating a new buffer may or may not be what OP wants to do. Of course, you could also filter the current buffer using :%! sed -E ...
